# I can't fetch data from the backend

Tags: angular

I can't download data from the backend with the sent token, testing in postman everything works, before introducing authorization everything worked correctly, what could be the problem?

here is a code:

```
  getOrders(): Observable<Order[]> {

    let token = this.authService.getToken();
    console.log(token);
    let head_obj = new HttpHeaders().set(
      'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token
    );
    
    console.log(head_obj);
    return this.httpClient.get<Order[]>(this.baseUrl,{headers:head_obj});
  }
```

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR9KZ.png),(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVXbF.png)

Answer (score 0):

here is a code:

```
getOrders(): Observable<Order[]> {
    let token = this.authService.getToken();
    console.log(token);
    let head_obj = new HttpHeaders().set(
      'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token
    );
    
    console.log(head_obj);
    return this.httpClient.get<Order[]>(this.baseUrl,{headers:head_obj});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think everything is set up correctly

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter(){
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(
            Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
            "Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"
            ,"Origin,Accept", "X-Requested-With",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method",
            "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
            "Origin", "Content-Type","Accept","Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
            "GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS"));
    var urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource =
            new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.
            registerCorsConfiguration("/**" ,
                    corsConfiguration);
    return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
}
```